# Не могу отобразить данные с сервера

Tags: javascript

Не могу отобразить данные, которые получаю с сервера:

```
import React from 'react'
import {MDBTable, MDBTableBody, MDBTableHead, MDBContainer, MDBCol} from 'mdbreact';
import Header from '../Register/stepData/Header'
import {MDBDataTable} from 'mdbreact';

export default class PriceList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            services: []
        };
    }

    renderServices  = arr => {
        return {
            columns: [
                {
                    label: '№',
                    field: 'number',
                    sort: 'asc',
                    width: 270
                },
                {
                    label: 'Название Услуги',
                    field: 'title',
                    sort: 'asc',
                    width: 150
                },
                {
                    label: 'Цена',
                    field: 'position',
                    sort: 'asc',
                    width: 270
                },
            ],
            rows: arr.data.map(item => ({
                number: item.id_service,
                title: item.title,
                office: item.price,
            }))
        };
    }
    getServices = _ => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/prices')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({services: response.data}))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getServices();
    }

    render() {
        const {services} = this.state
        console.log(services)
        return (
            <>
                <Header/>
                <MDBContainer>
                    <MDBDataTable
                        hover
                        data={services.map(this.renderServices)}
                    />
                </MDBContainer>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас при вызове `services.map(this.renderServices)` в метод передаются элементы.

Т.е, внутри `renderServices` переменная `arr` будет элементом вида:

```
{
    id_service: 1, title: "", price: 25
}
```

Поля `data` там нет. Следовательно, `arr.data` будет `undefined`, вот `arr.data.map` и падает.

Вместо `data={services.map(this.renderServices)}` написать `data={this.renderServices(services)}`, а вместое `arr.data.map` написать `arr.map`.

Comment: т е мне надо просто в `renderServices` `arr.map`?

Comment: @olliJes, вместо `data={services.map(this.renderServices)}` написать `data={this.renderServices(services)}`, а вместое `arr.data.map` написать `arr.map`.